# Terraform Azure AKS Cluster not exporting kubeconfig file

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to provision a kubernetes cluster on Azure (AKS) with Terraform. The provisioning works quite well but I can't get the kubeconfig from `kube_config_raw` exported to a file.

Below is my `main.tf` and `outputs.tf`. I supressed the `resource_group` and `user_assigned_identity` resources.

This is a resource I used for creating the configuration: https://learnk8s.io/terraform-aks

- `main.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=2.79.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "..."
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "myCluster"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "my-cluster-dns"

  default_node_pool {
    name            = "agentpool"
    node_count      = 1
    os_disk_size_gb = 64
    vm_size         = "Standard_B2ms"
  }

  identity {
    type                      = "UserAssigned"
    user_assigned_identity_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity.id
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity
  ]
}
```

- `outputs.tf` - I've tried "./kubeconfig" and "kubeconfig" in the filename but nothing gets exported anywhere

```
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  depends_on   = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks]
  filename     = "./kubeconfig"
  content      = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config_raw
}
```

**Bonus**: is it possible to export it directly to the existing `~/.kube/config` file? Like the `az aks get-credentials` command does?

Comment: hello @everspader, I ran the same code you have and kubeconfig file gets saved ., so if i am running from `PS C:\Users\user\terraform\aksconfig> ` giving file name `./kubeconfig`. it gets saved in the same folder i.e. `C:\Users\user\terraform\aksconfig\kubeconfig`. can you please check once again and let me know ?

Comment: Hello @everspader, If the answer was helpful, Could you please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> outputs.tf - I've tried "./kubeconfig" and "kubeconfig" in the
> filename but nothing gets exported anywhere

I tested the same code that you have and did `terraform-apply` , it saved the local file to the location where the apply was performed.

**For example:**

If I ran the `main.tf` file from `C:\Users\user\terraform\aksconfig>` as its present there then the `kubeconfig` file gets saved in the same path .

**Output:**

[image]

---

> **Bonus: is it possible to export it directly to the existing ~/.kube/config file? Like the az aks get-credentials command does?**

Path where the `az aks get-credentials --resource-group myresourcegroup --name myCluster` stores the config file:

[image]

**Code to save the script in the same path as az command:**

```
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  depends_on   = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks]
  filename     = "C:/Users/user/.kube/config" this is where the config file gets stored
  content      = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config_raw
}
```

**Output:**

**Exisitng config file in `/.kube/config`**

[image]

**New File overwrites the existing file :**

[image]

**Note:** Using `local_file` block here will completely overwrite the file not appending the context to the previous one . If you are looking for merging the content in a single file like az command does , then its not possible from terraform.

Comment: Hi @AnsumanBal-MT, thank you for your answer and for trying it out. I have recreated the cluster more than 5 times and the kubeconfig file never gets saved. I will try to change the path to where it saves to se if it helps in any way then I’ll let you know.

Comment: Hey @AnsumanBal-MT. I am trying with two different paths now:
`filename = "~/<path>/aks/kubeconfig"` and `filename = "~/.kube/config"` but no success yet. The file is just not saved. The cluster is created and I can see `kube_config_raw` in the `.tfstate`.

Comment: @everspader, may I know what operating system you are using and the terraform version also ?

Comment: Sure thing: Ubuntu 20.04  with Terraform v1.0.9 on linux_amd64

Comment: hello @everspader, i tested it on a ubuntu 20.04 machine with terraform version 1.0.9. and that also successfully saved the file , you can refer this [image](https://i.imgur.com/5s99tsF.png)

Comment: Hey @AnsumanBal-MT, we seem to be doing the exact same thing with the exact same environment. Do you have an idea of anything that could be interferring?

Comment: Unfortunately as i am not able to reproduce that issue , I am not sure why its not saving it for you even when its present in the state file and gets created.. can you share the apply output snapshot? like where it shows applied 2 etc.

Comment: Hey @AnsumanBal-MT, this is going to sound stupid but I decided to go the old route. Restared my computer then ran `terraform init/plan/apply` again and now the config file is saved. I will accept your answer because it is also a really good explanation! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Np , @everspader, glad to be of help!!